# is there a Mono Alternitive to user.dll setparent and SetWindowPos?

Tags: c#, mono, user32

I am trying to embed an application inside another one so the user can use the application in it.  I have this working correctly inside of a windows only applications but i don't want to limit it to windows so im going to convert all the normal C# code to a mono C# application witch is easy enough but im using some windows only code like the user32.dll so i was wondering if there is an alternative one i can use to get the same effect as the setParent and setWindowPos functions inside the user32.dll. it would be awesome if there is a cross platform option but if there is not is there atleast one i can use to get the same result for mac and linux?  At this time mainly mac.  I have been searching all over the place and i cant find qny alternatives to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find a different way than user32.dll on alternative platforms, the structure in for instance OSX and Linux is very different from Windows so you will have to go different ways. However depending on what you do there might be a different way to do things using only managed code. A good place for looking for managed alternatives is [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) which suggest that you can [use MDI instead of setParent](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetParent.html)

But describe what you want to accomplish with calls to setParent and setWindowPos and maybe a OSX solutions is available you can utilize.